# Wiring of two fans with individual switches and outlets

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am in the process of replacing my family room fans and I am confusing myself. I took pictures before taking the fans down to get the wiring correct, but between bad pics and second guessing myself, I am not positive how the wiring should look. Here is the situation...

I have my power coming from the panel into Fan A. From Fan A there is a line running to a light/fan combo switch. There is also a line that runs to an outlet. Lastly, there is the line the runs to Fan B.

Fan B has a line going to it's own light/fan combo switch and another line going to an outlet.

The pics wouldn't upload, but here is a diagram that I can figure out from the pics and other wiring diagrams I came across online. What needs to be changed? Sorry for the messy diagram too!

[image]

Comment: Can you post the photos at least?

Comment: Make sure you re-identify the whites going to the switches as hot wires by some permanent method, usually colored electrical tape. They should be black, red or blue but could be another color other than white or green. Otherwise, your diagram works with Kris' advice.

Comment: Try uploading the photos to [imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and posting links here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### As the drawing shows at each fan:

- Red to blue on fan
- Switched Black to black on fan
- White to white on fan.
- Blacks tied to one white are permanently hot, keep them tied back and do not wire to fan.
- Not shown: Bare copper to green.

Assuming the wiring at the switches and outlets was not altered, that should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the wiring is all setup and almost working. Not sure if you have any suggestion on this, but my switch is not working correctly. The fan 3 speed switch adjusts and turns  the fan on and off, but it also controls the lights, as if it was a dimmer. The light switch does turn the light switch on and off though. It is the same Lutron switch I have installed in the past without problem. Thanks!

Comment: @junta Without knowing the Lutron dual fan control model will be hard troubleshooting the problem.  At first guess, sounds like the red and blue are tied together in the fan, which they should be separated.  Or, the fan control is actually not a dual fan control.

Comment: Yep, I had the fan switch and light switch wire flipped in the switch. Thanks for the help!